# Kafka with manual offset management spring integration

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to Kafka, I am trying  to consume message from Kafka well i am able to that  with the help of basic Kafka spring integration example from [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/kafka/Application.java)

now I am able to read message from Kafka but I want to do the offset management   manually with spring integration, I am able to do this with KafkaConsumer using seek method I am able to go back in the que. I want to do the same with spring integration is there any example or doc available

Answer (score 4):

See [here](https://spring.io/blog/2016/06/07/spring-integration-kafka-support-2-0-0-release-candidate-is-now-available) and [here](https://spring.io/blog/2016/06/07/spring-for-apache-kafka-1-0-release-candidate-1-available).

The new Spring for Apache Kafka (currently based on the 0.9 client) supports setting initial offsets. See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.0.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#_kafkamessagelistenercontainer).

Use the listener container constructor that takes `TopicPartitionInitialOffset`s.

spring-integration-kafka 2.0 is re-written to be built on top of spring-kafka.

Both projects are at release candidate stage and the full releases should be available shortly.

Comment: Thank you #Gray, This is really helpful for me, I have one more Question listener container bean initialization will take place at startup time so that means at run time I cannot control the position right ?? like I can do that in  Kafka consumer's seek method

Comment: Not currently, you'd have to stop the container and create a new one to do it at runtime. I opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/129) to consider adding the feature.

Comment: HI Gary 
Can you please tell me what is the meaning of message driven pojos?
Actually I was reading the document and I found this term and I am not able to relate it.  
Thanks in advance ...

Comment: POJO = Plain Old Java Object - no special dependencies. Message-Driven = method is invoked as a result of a message being received.

Comment: HI Gary thanks for your quick reply ... from your reply, Below is my understanding, please correct me if I am wrong :- All it does is define a POJO to handle the messages received from a message Broker (Kind of delegation).

Comment: and above can be achieved with @KafkaListener Right.. this will give me ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record?

Comment: You can get the consumer record if the method signature is such; otherwise you can just get the payload and use `@Header` parameters to get the headers if you need them.